# How to add margins to code blocks in Jekyll?

Tags: css, jekyll

Currently code blocks on my Jekyll blog look like this:

[image]

I want them to have *margins* on the left like this:

[image]

Preferably, I would also like bigger *margins* on top and bottom.

Is it possible in Jekyll CSS? My current code base is at https://github.com/jjarzynski/jjarzynski.github.io/tree/master/_sass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `display: block; padding: 10px;` solved it.

Before:

```
.highlight code, .highlight pre {
  color:#fdce93;
  background-color:#3f3f3f;
}
```

After:

```
.highlight code, .highlight pre {
  color:#fdce93;
  background-color:#3f3f3f;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```